# Can I combine all four iptables lines into one statement?

Tags: iptables

I do search the meaing `RETURN` as iptable's target.

```
RETURN means stop traversing this chain  and  resume  at
       the  next rule in the previous (calling) chain.  If the end of a built-
       in chain is reached or a rule in a built-in chain with target RETURN is
       matched,  the  target specified by the chain policy determines the fate
       of the packet.
```

I feel it is hard to understand,and  for the following four iptables' commands

```
iptables -N syn-flood
iptables -A syn-flood -m limit --limit 100/s --limit-burst 150 -j RETURN
iptables -A syn-flood -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -j syn-flood
```

Can i combine them all into just one statement?

```
iptables -A INPUT -m limit --limit 100/s --limit-burst 150 -j DROP
```

If not,please make a clear explanation on the above four iptables' commands and `RETURN` in it.
Read more material,and Tomek'post ,i knew that the second case is a logical negation of the first one.

Is the following two lines equal to the four lines?

```
iptables -A INPUT -m limit --limit 100/s --limit-burst 150 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

Do they take the same effect?

Comment: Your combined statement would have the opposite effect; you would be dropping all traffic until it hit the burst limit, at which point you would start accepting traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at man page to understand how `limit` module works:

```
   limit
       This module matches at a limited rate using a token bucket  filter.   A
       rule  using  this extension will match until this limit is reached.
```

In the first case the packet enters `INPUT` chain an then goes to `syn-flood` chain (in a way this is similar to function call). The first line of `syn-flood` gets evaluated and all matching packets (which means all packets until the limit is reached) hit the `RETURN` target. The man page says this about it:

```
RETURN means stop traversing this chain  and  resume  at the  next rule
in the previous (calling) chain.
```

If you follow on my comment that it is similar to a function call this basically means  that the packet basically leaves the `syn-flood` chain and it resumes evaluation at the next statement of the caller chain. As `INPUT` chain ends here you will basically hit the `INPUT` chain's policy which by default is `ACCEPT`.

In the second case all packets matching a rule will hit the `DROP` target.

In a way the second case is a logical negation of the first one.

Comment: Should i  write the following two lines which is equal to the four lines?

Comment: iptables -A INPUT -m limit --limit 100/s --limit-burst 150 -j ACCEPT

Comment: iptables -A INPUT -j DROP

Answer (score 0):

iptables are pretty slick but there is one unfortunate feature. Inserting or deleting an entry requires pulling the whole iptables from kernel, modifying it, and pushing it back in.

Every single call to a plain `iptables` command results in two kernel space to user space operations. `iptables-restore` allows you to keep the number of pulls and pushes at exactly two combined regardless of how many operations you do within.

Now, `-N` creates a new chain within the `filter` table (default).

The first `-A` command appends (at the end) a new rule to this chain and limits the number of processed packets as specified and if the limit has not been reached `RETURN` causes the traversal of this chain to end. Meaning the second `-A` will not get hit.

If, however, the limit has been reached, the traversal continues and the next `-A` gets hit and `DROP` causes the packet to be dropped.

The last `-I` inserts a non conditional jump to this newly created chain `syn-flood`. With no number specified for `-I`, the rule gets inserted at the top.

Hope this covers it.

Edit: An example of how to use `iptables-restore`

Create a file with the following content and change the builtin chains' default policy to your liking:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-N syn-flood
-A syn-flood -m limit --limit 100/s --limit-burst 150 -j RETURN
-A syn-flood -j DROP
-I INPUT -j syn-flood 
COMMIT
```

and run `iptables-restore <filename>`.